# Are 過ぎ and 後 always interchangeable when used as a suffix in time expressions?

Tags: expressions, suffixes, time

Lots of sites say that **過ぎ{すぎ}** means *past* and that **後{ご}** means *after* when using them as a suffix in time expressions. However, when I read sentences with English translations through the internet then the two suffix translations are the same.

So my question is: are there any differences between the two suffixes? Or are they interchangeable?

For example:

> もう８時{じ}過ぎ{すぎ}だ。= もう８時{じ}後{ご}だ。

> 午後{ごご}4時{じ}過ぎ{すぎ}には家{いえ}にいます。 =  午後{ごご}4時{じ}後{ご}には家{いえ}にいます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N時過ぎ is *(a few minutes) past N o'clock* and opposite of N時前=*(a few minutes) to N o'clock*.

後{ご} cannot come after N時: 8時後 etc are wrong. Also, it does not have the meaning of *shortly* that 過ぎ has.

- 終業後 after work
- 完了後 after completion

When you say *after N o'clock'*, e.g., like in the following,

- When will you be available (say, for meeting) after 2 o'clock?

以降 or より後{あと} is used.

- 2時以降で/2時より後でご都合の良い時間はありますか.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, then the 後{ご} suffix can be used with noun (but not with time expression) and doesn't have time limit (like few minutes), am I right?

Comment: @ZeroProcess Generally yes. But most nouns that can be appended by 後 would be kango.